# very complex RegEx

Tags: php, regex

so there's a string,

```
<?php

$string = <<<STR

/\!@#$%^&*()?.,djasijdiwqpk,=-c./zcxzo123154897kp02ldz.,world90iops02&&&8ks

STR;
```

I want to replace everything to NULL, except word "world" and number 1 and 3,

I just want to get "world13" or "world31" from that string USING regular expressions

I have already implemented basic solution,
via strpos() and substr() and this is works as excepted. But I need to do this via RegExp

The question is:

**Is it possible to extract that word using RegEx?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~(world(?:(31|13))~i`. The `'i'` makes the regex case insensitive. The `?:` is there so it doesn't put it in the matches array in a separate result. Wouldn't say it's very complex, by the way :)  If you want *every* 1 and 3 in there, you can use `~(world|1|3)~i`.

Comment: You lie! Expression will not extract string `world13` from the OPs `$string`!

Comment: @Qtax Nope, it won't, you're absolutely right about that. Nevertheless, I assumed he actually wanted "world31" or "world13", instead of rigidly complaining that his example string isn't correct. So yeah, his question could've been better, but the solution to his question appears to be given. Grow up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to extract that word using RegEx?

Yes. You can use this regular expression:

```
(world)
```

---

> I know, that, But I can't extract world13 or world31

Ah, I understand! You can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/.*/s', 'world13', $string);
```

Comment: yeah I know, that, But I can't extract world13 or world31

Comment: Wonderful, but I propose to simplify it to `$string = 'world13';`

Comment: @zerkms, very good suggestion! I propose you post it as answer so we can vote on it.

Comment: @xdazz, I understand problem, it never extract `world31`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to find things you need and then join them to a string.

```
preg_match_all('/world|[13]/', $string, $matches);
$ret = join($matches[0]);
```